# VBA run time error 3704 with recordset in Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

Good day.

When this piece of code hits "While Not objMyRecordset.EOF", I receive run time error 3704. In addition to this, when I hover over the "objMyRecordset" portion of "strPSTPath = CStr(objMyRecordset("PSTPath"))", i see error beginning "objMyRecordSet(PS... =

My SQL query works fine when used in SQL server management studio. The error occurs instantaneously upon hitting the line in question. I have stepped through the code line by line. Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
Sub Button3_Click()

'******
'Variables
Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command
Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

'Open connection
objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=XXXX;Data Source=XXXX"
objMyConn.Open

'Set and execute SQL command
Set objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
objMyCmd.CommandText = "<Valid SQL Command removed for public code display>"
objMyCmd.CommandType = adCmdText

'Open recordset
Set objMyRecordset.Source = objMyCmd
objMyRecordset.Open objMyCmd


While Not objMyRecordset.EOF

    strPSTPath = CStr(objMyRecordset("PSTPath"))
    MsgBox strPSTPath

    objMyRecordset.MoveNext
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: You're opening your recordset twice - using both `Open` and `Excecute` - you only need one of those.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I added that while debugging. Removing it, I encounter the same error. I'll edit my example accordingly.

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: "Operation is not allowed when the object is closed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tracked down the problem. The connection string was incorrect for the version of SQL on this particular server. Changed the connection string to:

Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=XXXX;Database=XXXX;Trusted_Connection=yes;

Now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Button3_Click()

Dim SQL As String, strPSTPath As String
Dim objMyConn, objMyRecordset

    Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

    objMyConn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _
          "Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=XXXX;Data Source=XXXX"

    SQL = "<Valid SQL Command removed for public code display>"

    objMyRecordset.Open SQL, objMyConn

    While Not objMyRecordset.EOF
        strPSTPath = CStr(objMyRecordset("PSTPath"))
        MsgBox strPSTPath
        objMyRecordset.MoveNext
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Using this code ended with the same error, so I used a different connection string and query (essentially hitting another SQL server) and the error vanished. Thanks for your help - i'm certain there's a problem outside the code now.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I used VBA and ADODB, but instead of opening the recordset object, I believe you need to execute the command object:

```
set objMyRecordset = objMyCmd.Execute
```

Have a look at this [link](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?552665-Database-How-do-I-use-an-ADO-Command-object).